# Using switch with if else statement to toggle JavaScript calculator mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a JavaScript calculator with a mode button that is supposed to toggle between radian and degree mode via a switch. If the value of the button is either `DEG` or `RAD`, clicking on the cosine button will execute either the `cos` function or the `cosDeg` function (see below):

```
$('#button-mode').click(function() {

  var type = $(this).val(),
      $div = $('#mode');

        switch (type) {
        case 'DEG':
            $div.html('DEG');
            $('#button-mode').html('Rad');
            $('#button-mode').val('RAD');     
            break;

        case 'RAD':
            $div.html('RAD');                
            $('#button-mode').html('Deg');
            $('#button-mode').val('DEG');           
            break;
                }

});

if ($("#button-mode").val() === 'DEG') {
    $('#button-cos').click(function() {
    if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
        cos(this.form);
      $('#disp').addClass("result");
      }
      console.log('cos');
      });
    }
else if ($("#button-mode").val() === 'RAD') {
    $('#button-cos').click(function() {
    if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
        cosDeg(this.form);
      $('#disp').addClass("result");
      }
      console.log('cosDeg');
      });
    }
```

The switch seems to be working fine in that the correct HTML appears in both the `button` and the `#mode` div, but clicking on `#button-cos` in either case executes the `cos` function. I am at a loss as for why this happens.
Also, and this may be why this is happening, the button is given by:

```
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-mode" value="DEG">Deg</button>
```

How can I change my code to get this working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only define one handler for your button-cos click event, and determine the correct function to call inside of that function.

```
$('#button-cos').click(function() {
    if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) {
        if($("#button-mode").val() === 'DEG'){
            cosDeg(this.form);
        } else{
            cos(this.form);
        }
      $('#disp').addClass("result");
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is cause you add new event listeners, but not remove previously added, so both click handlers executes.

You can use  `document.getElementById('button-cos').onclick=function() {...}` instead of `$('#button-cos').click(function() {...}` it will remove previous handler and add new one.
But also it seems that code does not add events after clicking `button-mode`.

So, much better is to move if statements (`if ($("#button-mode").val() === '...')`) inside event handler. In that case you will need to add click handler only once.